# How addEventListener in nested template?

Tags: polymer

In the following code:

```
<body unresolved fullbleed layout vertical>
    <template is="auto-binding" id="app">
        <core-ajax auto url="http://testesapi.azurewebsites.net/api/padaria" params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}' handleAs="json" response="{{produtos}}" id="ajax"></core-ajax>
        <template id="template2" repeat="{{prod in produtos}}">
            <form class="myForm" is="ajax-form" action="http://testesapi.azurewebsites.net/api/padaria" method="put">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" is="core-input" value="{{prod.id}}">
                <paper-input name="nome" label="Nome" value="{{prod.nome}}" floatinglabel></paper-input>
                <paper-input name="Preco" label="Preço" value="{{prod.Preco}}" floatinglabel>></paper-input>
                <button type="submit">SALVAR</button>
            </form>
        </template>
    </template>
</body>
```

How can I add an Event Listener to ".myForm"? I need to call core-ajax go() method after ajax-form is 'submitted'.

My problem is that querySelectorAll('.myForm') is resulting null, so it appears it's not in the DOM yet.

I tried to put querySelector inside this (but no success):

```
app.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {});
```

It's a Polymer app.

**Update 1**

I got take the nested template giving it an id of "template2" and:

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.addEventListener('template-bound', function() 
    var template2 = app.$.template2;
    <== question now is: how to "for each" the forms inside template2 to add an Event Listener?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just adding declarative event handlers (on-*event* attributes)? ajax-form has `submitting` and `submitted` events, so presumably you could do something like:

`<form class="myForm" is="ajax-form" on-submitting="myHandler" action="http://testesapi.azurewebsites.net/api/padaria" method="put">`

Answer (score 0):

With `querySelectorAll('.myForm')[0]` this specifies the 1st element of that kind.

Currently for perfrormance (tiny gain) you can use getElementById() if you have just 1 form.

Edit:

Here's a rough example of using querySelector & querySelectorAll.

```
var form = document.querySelectorAll('.myForm')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

var form = document.querySelector('.myForm2').style.backgroundColor = 'green';

**For created elements** querySelectorAll is useless as it only returns a static list.You can create an element and get the element via the example using ID as it returns the actual node list.

```
var section = document.getElementById('section');
section.children[3];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kroq55td/1/

Comment: My problem is that myForm is null (in other words, length = 0). I forgot to mention that it's a Polymer app.

Comment: ...and I need to add an Event Listener to all the forms, not just the first